What textbooks/papers should I read to try to make this rigorous?
Consider a surface of revolution $S$ and an embedding $e:S \hookrightarrow X^3$ for $X^3=[0,1]^3$ with cone points $p,q$ elements of $\partial X^3$ where $\partial X^3=X^3-(0,1)^3$ for $\mathrm {sup}~ \mathrm{dist}(p,q)=\sqrt{3}$. It can be shown that there exists a unique $\rho_{\mathrm{max}}=\mathrm{max} \lbrace \mathrm{vol}(S) \rbrace_{p,q}$ assuming $S$ must remain a surface of revolution and have constant positive Gaussian curvature. Building out copies of $S$ for all pairs of vertices on $X^3$ we obtain a curved or equivalently an abstract stellated octahedron. Let's denote the union of the four surfaces as $\zeta=:S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3 \cup S_4$.
I want to look at the set of all vector fields on $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ that sends flows from all cone points lying on the plane $z=0$ to the plane $z=1$. If we add all pairs of vectors whose tips lie on the intersection regions of $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ we get a space of nontrivial vector bundles. Here I'll ignore the exactly six points where we must add four vectors instead of two.

What is the mathematical significance of the way the vectors alternate (while traveling around a closed loop $\gamma$) between pointing "inward" into $\zeta$ and "outward" away from $\zeta$?

This should be very related to spinors, invented by Élie Cartan in 1913, in my opinion, which are very important in theoretical physics and mathematics. Since I'm looking for references,

what might I read to help understand and make rigorous what I've described only qualitatively?

